# Wordpress plugin to redirect to login first

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, plugins, buddypress

I have a WordPress site which I am using to teach online. Some of the courses are free but I want users to login before they are able to take the free courses. The users are free to visit the site but they should be logged to take the free course. If a user clicks a link to take a course, they will be redirected to login and then they can take the course.

I need a plugin to do this for me. Any recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/ or build one yourself

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a plugin for this

See this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Add the shortcode/function provided by this plugin to the page you want to be redirected to the first login. And set conditions for it as well and the condition you want is that the page should be redirected to the login page only if the user is not logged in and if he/she is logged in then they should not be redirected